# Magento 2 product import by PHP (Configurable,Categories)

Tags: magento2, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport

In Magento 1 I use http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/ for product/category tree import.For Magento 2 I found https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2 but seems like it does not provide configurable products and product/category linking. Maybe there is some tool like in M1 that extends Import/Export module functionality with PHP endpoints ?

Comment: Or I should us class from magento catalog product api ? But then It will be slow, save every product.